# how to make a optimization table component in react

Tags: reactjs, optimization

I developed logic to process the data fetched and then inject it into the Table Component. If there were 100 data (rows) and 9 columns, I thought that 900 pieces of data would need to be rendered, and I expected that there would be no problem with rendering speed. However, when rendering, the calculation speed took about 3 seconds, and when I took a look at the console, I found that there were many other values ​​in the object.
[object image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeU5b.jpg)

1. When injecting processed data into a table, what format should the data be injected in?

```js
  const dataSource = dataList
    ? dataList.map((data) => {
        const tableData: TableDataType = {
          key: data.id,
          username: <BM>{data.username}</BM>,
          name: <BM>{data.name}</BM>,
          role: <BM>{data.role}</BM>,
          isActive: <BM>{data.isActive ? '활성화' : '비활성화'}</BM>,
          edit: (
            <IconPencil
              color={theme.icon.primary}
              style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
              onClick={() => {
                setEditForm(data);
                handleEditModalOpen(data.id);
              }}
            />
          ),
        };
        return tableData;
      })
    : [];
```

2. If you only want to change the value of one column in a table, what method will you use other than rendering the entire table?

```js
 const getConvertedRow = (rowData: any, dataId: string, column: ColumnType) => {
    return (
      <RowComponent
        key={nanoid()}
        rowData={rowData}
        column={column}
        dataId={dataId}
        columnHeight={columnHeight}
        onClickRow={onClickRow}
      />
    );
  };

  const getConvertedColumn = (dataId: string, data: any) => {
    return (
      <ColumnComponent key={dataId} checked={data['columnChecked']}>
        {columns.map((column) => {
          return getConvertedRow(data[column.key], dataId, column);
        })}
      </ColumnComponent>
    );
  };

  const convertedDataSource = useMemo(() => {
    return dataSource.map((data: any) => getConvertedColumn(data.key, data));
  }, [dataSource, changedColumnId]);
```

3. I am not sure if the TableDataType was written correctly.

```js
export interface TableDataType {
  [property: string]: React.ReactNode;
}
```

4. My guess is that Styled Components are also responsible for slow rendering speed, but the exact reason for the slow rendering speed has not yet been determined. (It seems to be a problem with the format of the data being injected, but it is also a follow-up question to number 1.)

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the images, and post the code itself as text. Also browsers can render thousands of DOM elements with no performance issues. You can profile your app with the Chrome debugger profiler to see what the slowdown is.